# Monitor trap is received from agent

Tags: linux, windows, zenoss

I have an agent that monitors windows event log and looks for service up/down messages, and sends these messages as trap to zenoss. The agent is set to be run in windows scheduler. The agent is deployed in client device. How can I monitor the agent from zenoss and see whether trap is received at zenoss at regular intervals?